# "FormatException was unhandled" Input string was not in a correct format

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net

Here I am trying to write a function that returns me value based on the following condition...

IF

Variable is NULL return me DBNull.Value

ELSE

Convert Variable into DataType whose DataTypeCode has been provided to me as a parameter of function. eg.

Now while converting a variable into required DataType, an exception is thrown "FormatException was unhandled". Input string was not in a correct format.

How do I resolve this error please help.

Here is my code...

```
    public object ReturnDBNullOrRequiredDatatype(object IsThisObjectANull, TypeCode DataTypeCode)

    {
return IsThisObjectANull == null ? DBNull.Value : Convert.ChangeType(IsThisObjectANull, DataTypeCode);

    }
```

i am calling this function as
ReturnDBNullOrRequiredDatatype(txtFirstName.text, TypeCode of an Integer variable)
2nd parameter is a data type into which first parameter is to be converted.

I am trying to return this value to

SqlParameter spAmount = new SqlParameter(...)
    spName.value=DbNull.value

or

SqlParameter spName = new SqlParameter(...)
 spAmount.value=Cint(txtName.text)

I am trying to do this with that function.
I am making sure that the value being passed to that function will fulfill my conversion type but this error is still occuring.

Comment: Here I am trying to create a function that can convert any datatype into another datatype as desired by a programmer.

Parameter can be string or int or datetime.

Comment: Please provide input parameters for your method with which it fails

Comment: ReturnDBNullOrRequiredDatatype(txtAmount.text,TypeCode.Int);

Comment: I mean parameter values, not names.

Comment: I will be checking txtAmount.text for being numeric b4 passing.

Comment: What is the value of txtAmount.text?

Comment: ReturnDBNullOrRequiredDatatype("123",TypeCode.Int);

Comment: ReturnDBNullOrRequiredDatatype(DateTime.Now(),TypeCode.DateTime);     This should also be converted thru this function which it is failing to do.

Comment: "123" and TypeCode.Int32 works for me.

Comment: `static void Main(String[] args){ Console.Write(Convert.ChangeType("123", TypeCode.Int32));
}' works without exceptions. Another example you provided also works fine.

Comment: Please provide code example that fails, or input parameter values for which you get an exception.

Comment: @Roman Boiko: @itowlson:  ReturnDBNullOrRequiredDatatype("123",TypeCode.Int);  this doesn't works when i tries to call this with different different parameters. It works fine with strings and int but fails to run with datetime and vice versa

Comment: Try to run this with ReturnDBNullOrRequiredDatatype("123",TypeCode.Int); &  ReturnDBNullOrRequiredDatatype(DateTime.Now(),TypeCode.DateTime);

Comment: That's exactly what we did. Except that you shouldn't write () after DateTime.Now (it's a property).

Comment: TypeCode.Int and DateTime.Now() don't exist, but both of those work for me with TypeCode.Int32 and DateTime.Now.  As Roman has suggested, why not provide a *complete* (buildable) code example to help us reproduce the error you're seeing?

Comment: @itowlson: actually this function is being called after a call of series of function calls so it doesn't seems possible to post whole code here.

Comment: Plz check the comments of Fredrik Mörk below. Does this code runs successfully for NULL value.

Comment: No, but you can create a small repro case that calls *just this function* with some literal inputs.  You don't have to post your *actual* program, but a smaller program that shows the same error.

Comment: what if CheckValue contains null in this function call. Will it run correct as now it should return DBNull.Value.   ReturnDBNullOrRequiredDatatype(CheckValue,TypeCode.DateTime);

Comment: It will work correctly. By 'correctly' I mean in the way you described above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation for [`Convert.IsDBNull`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert.isdbnull.aspx) says the following:

> Returns an indication whether the specified object is of type DBNull.

The documentation also specifically states that `DBNull.Value` is not equivalent to a null reference or `string.Empty`.

So the method should return false if you pass `null` or an empty string to it. I believe that what you really want to do is this:

```
if (IsThisObjectANull == null)
    return DBNull.Value;
else
    return Convert.ChangeType(IsThisObjectANull, DataTypeCode);
```

...or the shorter version:

```
return IsThisObjectANull == null ? DBNull.Value : Convert.ChangeType(IsThisObjectANull, DataTypeCode);
```

Comment: @Fredrik Mörk: yes i want this to be done as u wrote. But i m not clear with your first two lines.

Comment: @Shanantu: I am just trying to point out that there is a difference between `null` and `DBNull.Value`. `DBNull.Value` is not a null reference (it is a `DBNull` instance), and `Convert.IsDBNull` checks whether the passed object is a `DBNull` object. Obviously, a null reference is not a `DBNull` object, so the method should return false. Since you in your question stated that you wanted to check if the input was a null reference, `Convert.IsDBNull` cannot do the job for you.

Comment: @Fredrik Mörk: Do u mean to say, I cant return DBNull.Value which i think it should as it should also be of object type. Doesn't it comes under this category. I mean which is the parent class of DBNull.Value, is it an object or not. I think u seems to be right. Suggest me some other alternative to do the same in case it does'nt work.

Comment: @Shantanu: Object is parent class of all other classes, including DBNull.Value.

Comment: @Shanatu: your method could (and probably should) return `DBNull.Value`. All I am saying is that you cannot use `Convert.IsDBNull` to test for `null`. That is not what that method does. It tests for `DBNull` objects. This means that if you pass `null` to your original code, it will try to convert that null to the given type, which will fail for int, DateTime and all other value types. This is a bug in your code. However, I don't think this is the problem that you are facing right now (guessing from comments), since this would give you an `InvalidCastException`, not a `FormatException`.

Comment: So shouldn't it return DBNull.Value. As I am not sure now after reading Fredrik Mörk's Comments

Comment: @Fredrik Mörk: I am xtremly sry for misunderstooding u. Actually i was doing a blunder. Thx for correcting me. This error was troubling me for 3 days. Trillion ton thanks to all supportors. @Fredrik Mörk @Roman Boiko @itowlson
Thx for ur patience.

Comment: Shantanu: You're welcome. Did it help? Is your problem solved?

Comment: Just give me few more moments. But u get my 1 bug

Comment: if (Convert.IsDBNull(IsThisObjectANull) == true)
            return DBNull.Value;
        else
            return Convert.ChangeType(IsThisObjectANull, DataTypeCode);

Comment: @Roman Boiko: Thx for the help my problem got resolved. There was a bug only. I was entering wrong input at the time of checking that;s why it was giving me format exception

Answer (score 1):

The FormatException is telling you that the object (in your case a string) cannot be converted to the requested type (in your case, integer).  Probably the string being passed in is not a valid number, e.g. "abc" rather than "123"; or, for your DateTime case, it's not a valid date-time string for the current culture, e.g. "12/31/2009 12:34:56" when you're in a dd/MM/yyyy locale.  Try passing an IFormatProvider, such as CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, that maps to the date-time format you are expecting your users to type in.

Comment: ...or it's a type that's not supported like a byte[] or a reference type.

Comment: Good point, though he says he's passing in txtFirstName.Text as the first arg, so I'm guessing it's a string.

Comment: dont go over the name that it depicts. the data type that i m passing into which first value is to be converted will surely match the data type into which it has to be converted.

Comment: txtObject.text will always have value according to the 2nd parameter. If 2nd parameter is a string 1st parameter will always be a string, if it is 'int' then 1st parameter will have int as "123".